# Issue with Deserialization with xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting error with deserialization. It says error in xml document.

```
public T XmlDeserialiseResponseObject<T>(string xml)
        {
            T returnedXmlClass;

            try
            {
                xml = XmlResponseObjectCleaner(xml);

                var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xml);
                var reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement);
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                returnedXmlClass = (T)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex; 
            }
            return returnedXmlClass;
        }
```

My XML :

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/elope/'><soap:Body><GetBenefitStatusFault xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.somesite.co.za/somesite/some/' schemaVersion='1.0'>
    <ErrorCode>3513</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorMessage>Membership details not valid: Match on initial not found</ErrorMessage>
</GetBenefitStatusFault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

XmlResponseObjectCleaner:

```
 private string XmlResponseObjectCleaner(string xml)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(xml);

            sb.Replace(@"""", "'");
            sb.Replace("<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>", "");
            sb.Replace("</env:Envelope>", "");
            sb.Replace("<env:Header/>", "");
            sb.Replace("<env:Body>", "");
            sb.Replace("ns3:", "");
            sb.Replace("ns2:", "");
            sb.Replace("</env:Body>", "");
            sb.Replace("env", "");
            sb.Replace("T00:00:00.000+02:00", "");
            sb.Replace("T00:00:00.000Z", "");

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: oof, that "cleaner" is probably not a good idea...

Comment: Thanks Marc. Is there are a better way.

Comment: You need to look at the xml _after_ you've "cleaned" it to see if it's valid. I agree with Marc, though - don't clean it - just pull the whole document into a reader and pass the root note that you want to deserialize to the deserializer. (e.g. `doc.SelectSingleNode("//GetBenefitStatusFault")`

Comment: I assume you are getting this xml from some service. Do you have a description of this service as a WSDL or ASMX file? If so, you should automatically generate a set of classes to access this service. And you don't have to manually work with xml.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. load the XML into a DOM and pick out the Body element and parse the OuterXml from there
2. start at the envelope

Here's an approach for 2:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string xml = @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/elope/'><soap:Body><GetBenefitStatusFault xmlns:ns2='http://schemas.somesite.co.za/somesite/some/' schemaVersion='1.0'>
    <ErrorCode>3513</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorMessage>Membership details not valid: Match on initial not found</ErrorMessage>
</GetBenefitStatusFault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

        var obj = XmlDeserialiseResponseObject<GetBenefitBody>(xml);
        if (obj.GetBenefitStatusFault is Fault f)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(f.ErrorCode);
            System.Console.WriteLine(f.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    public static T XmlDeserialiseResponseObject<T>(string xml)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope<T>));
        var obj = (Envelope<T>)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        return obj.Body;
    }
}

[XmlRoot("Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/elope/")]
public class Envelope<T>
{
    public T Body { get; set; }
}

public class GetBenefitBody
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public Fault GetBenefitStatusFault { get; set; }
}
public class Fault
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for all the effort taken to code and answer me. Much apperciate it. But i am stilling get error i.e  There is an error in XML document (1, 2)

Comment: @prathimagnanak the code I posted literally works as-is. If your code/xml is different: you're going to need to help me with context

Comment: sorry for delayed response. yes, it did work. Thank you so much